# Loading large data from database with Symfony2 and Doctrine 2

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm beginner on *Symfony2*.

I have a Regions-Countries-States-Cities database with more of 2,000,000 results. I have 8 entities:

```
Region (recursive with itself) - RegionTranslation

Country - CountryTranslation

State (recursive with itself) - StateTranslation

City - CityTranslation
```

The thing is that when I want to load a countries list (only 250 registers in a pulldown, for example) Symfony+Doctrine load all entities structure (all states of all countries, and all cities of all states, with their respective translations).

I think that it spends a lot of memory.

What's the correct method to do it? Can I load only Country (and translations) with this structure? Any idea?

Comment: Sure You can load all the data from just one entity, assuming there are no dependencies with data from the other entities.

Comment: Doctrine has lazy loading enabled by default. It should only load those entities when you need them. Maybe you have disabled that by accident?

Comment: How I can check if lazy loading is enabled? how I can enable it?
I think that's disabled, because when I do a var_dump() of some Entity, it try to show all recursive entities and crashes my browser. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem for objected that are unassociated.  Your best bet is to use select2's ajax loading (http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/), which will give a limited number of items in the search box, and also narrow searches down by what is typed in the box.

A few things things need to be coded:

A javascript file:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.select2thing').select2({
          minimumInputLength:1
        ,width: "100%"
        ,ajax: {
          url: <<path>> + "entity/json"
         ,dataType: 'jsonp'
         ,quitMillis: 100
         ,data: function (term, page) {
         return {
            q: term, // search term
            limit: 20,
            page: page
         };
        }
    ,results: function (data, page) {
      var more = (page * 20) < data.total;
      return { results: data.objects, more: more };
    }
    }
    });

    }
```

A jsonAction in the controller:

```
    /**
    * Lists all Thing entities return in json format
    *
    */
    public function jsonAction(Request $request)
    {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $rep = $em->getRepository('yourBundle:Thing');
      $qb = $rep->createQueryBuilder('e');

      $limit = $request->query->get('limit');
      $current = $request->query->get('current');
      $page=$request->query->get('page');
      $queries=$request->query->get('q');
      $qarray=explode(",", $queries);

      $entities=$rep->getJSON($qarray, $page, $limit);
      $total=$rep->getJSONCount($qarray);
      $callback=$request->query->get('callback');

      return $this->render('yourBundle:Thing:json.html.twig'
         , array(
             'entities'  => $entities
            ,'callback'  => $callback
            ,'total'     => $total
         )
      );
    }
```

A twig template (json.html.twig, possibly customized to display more)

```
    {{callback}}(
    { "objects" :
    [
    {% for entity in entities %}
    { "id": "{{entity.id}}", "text": "{{entity}}""}
    {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    ],
     "total": {{total}}
    }
    )
```

A transformer:

```
    use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;
    use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
    use yourBundle\Entity\Thing;

    class ThingTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var ObjectManager
         */
        private $em;

        /**
         * @param ObjectManager $em
         */
        public function __construct(ObjectManager $em)
        {
            $this->em = $em;
        }

        /**
         * Transforms an object (thing) to a string (id).
         *
         * @param  Issue|null $thing
         * @return string
         */
        public function transform($thing)
        {
            if (null === $thing) {return "";}
            if (is_object($thing) && "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection"==get_class($thing)){
              $entity->map(function ($ob){return $ob->getId();});
              return implode(",",$thing->toArray());
            }
            return $thing;
        }

        /**
         * Transforms a string (id) to an object (thing).
         *
         * @param  string $id
         * @return Issue|null
         * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (thing) is not found.
         */
        public function reverseTransform($id)
        {
            if (!$id) {
                return null;
            }

            //if (is_array($id)){
              $qb=$this->em
                ->getRepository('yourBundle:Thing')
                ->createQueryBuilder('t');
              $thing=$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('t.id', $id))->getQuery()->getResult();

              if (null === $entity) {
                throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                    'A thing with id "%s" does not exist!',
                    $id
                ));
            }

            return $thing;
        }
    }
```

Your Controller using the select2 control will have to pass the 'em' to the form builder:

```
  $editForm = $this->createForm(new ThingType()
     ,$entity
     ,array(
        'attr' => array(
            'securitycontext' => $sc
           ,'em'              => $this->getDoctrine()
                                      ->getEntityManager()
        )
     )
  );
```

And in your form type:

```
  if (isset($options['attr']['em'])){ $em = $options['attr']['em'];} else {$em=null;}

  $transformer = new ThingTransformer($em);
  $builder->add(
      $builder->create('thing'
         ,'hidden'
         ,array(
             'by_reference' => false
            ,'required' => false
            ,'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'select2thing'
            )
         )
      )
      ->prependNormTransformer($transformer)
  );
```

Comment: I load it with ajax. But only to load the countries structures take a lot of time (5-10 secs)... and reload states when country selected the same (5-10 secs).

Comment: Adjust your query to only get some of the results to get better speed.  I used $limit to only fetch some of the results, and this is passed as limited by select2.  This should speed things up significantly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the [hydration mode](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html?highlight=hydrate#hydration-modes), using array consumes less memory than creating objects.

Other way you can achieve this is using [iterations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing) to avoid memory problems:

Finally I think you can't load all without spending a lot of time and memory, so, why not make several queries to load the whole data?