# select2 slow speed : OutOfMemoryException

Tags: php, symfony, autocomplete, jquery-select2

i'm using select2 (v4.0.1) to request the data from ma database. when the list is huge more than 2000 items it really slows down. i'm looking a way to sloved this problem.

This html and script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".auto").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a state",
        allowClear: true,
        width:"100%"
    });
});
```

**news.html.twig**

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-group form-group-lg form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-plane input-icon"></i><label>From:</label>
{{ form_widget(form.airport, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control auto',} }) }}
 {{ form_errors(form.airport) }}</div></div>

<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group form-group-lg form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-plane input-icon"></i>
<label>To:</label>{{ form_widget(form.airport1, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control auto',} }) }}{{ form_errors(form.airport1) }}</div></div>
```

i find this in stackoverflow, but it doesn't work:

```
// Function to shuffle the demo data
var shuffle = function (str) {
        return str.split('').sort(function () {
            return 0.5 - Math.random();
        }).join('');
    };
    $(function () {
        $('#.auto').select2({
        // For demonstration purposes we first make
        // a huge array of demo data (20 000 items)
        // Heads up; for the _.map and _.filter function i use underscore (actually lo-dash) here
            data             : _.map(_.range(1, 20000), function (i) {
                return {
                    id  : i,
                    text: shuffle('te ststr ing to shuffle') + ' ' + i
                };
            }),
            // NOT NEEDED: These are just css for the demo data
            dropdownCssClass : 'capitalize',
            containerCssClass: 'capitalize',
            // configure as multiple select
            multiple         : true,
            // text for loading more results
            formatLoadMore   : 'Loading more...',
            query            : function (q) {
            // pageSize is number of results to show in dropdown
                var pageSize,
                    results;
                    pageSize = 20;
                    results  = _.filter(this.data, function (e) {
                        return (q.term === "" || e.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(q.term.toUpperCase()) >= 0);
                 });
                q.callback({
                    results: results.slice((q.page - 1) * pageSize, q.page * pageSize),
                    // retrieve more when user hits bottom
                    more   : results.length >= q.page * pageSize
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: How do you get the data for your select2? Can you show that?

Comment: this is how i get the data : 
            `->add('airport', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
                'class' => 'FLYBookingsBundle:IataAirportCodes',
                'property' => 'airport',

            ))

            ->add('airport1', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
                'class' => 'FLYBookingsBundle:IataAirportCodes',
                'property' => 'airport',

            ))`

Comment: Can't you just get the values which match your 'search word' ? And only load values when typing? It'll decrease the results.

Comment: Here is an example of how to load the data with JQuery for performance : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245038/speed-up-select2-using-ajax-with-php?rq=1

Comment: Sorry to reply only now. The best way should be to get the data that match with the search word as you said. i only found some examples that explain how to do it remotely. But in my case my items (airport) are in my database. Do you have an example that explain how to pull the data from the database and get the values which match with the search word ? i'm using symfony 2.7

Comment: There is an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526857/loading-large-data-from-database-with-symfony2-and-doctrine-2

Comment: i will try it right now. i will Let you know if it works. thx